# What should I use instead of QDesktopWidget::resized in Qt 6?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt6

I'm in the process of converting a project from Qt 5 to Qt 6. I previously used the signal `QDesktopWidget::resized` to be notified of when anything about the current screen configuration changed, be it the resolution of one screen or the arrangement of multiple screens.

However, `QDesktopWidget` has been removed from Qt 6, and I don't see anything that replaces this specific signal.

While `QScreen` is obviously intended to be used as a replaced to `QDesktopWidget`, and I can use various signals of `QScreen` to be notified of the changes of *one specific screen*, there doesn't appear to be any signal that will notify me of changes to *any* screen, regardless of what that change is.

There also doesn't seem to be an equivalent signal on `QGuiApplication` either.

The only solution I can think of is to make use of the `QGuiApplication::screenAdded` signal, and every time a new screen is added, connect to its `geometryChanged` signal. <strike>But, quite frankly, that totally sucks, and is not even a workable solution. Not only is it more crufty code to do something that used to be a one liner, it also now means I'm going to have *multiple* signals fire every time something about the screen configuration changes, rather than just one. And I don't know how many signals will fire because any one configuration operation is not guaranteed to change every screen!</strike> (I was mistaken that `QDesktopWidget::resized` only fired once!)

Comment: Not a good solution, but as a work-around for the problem you mention in your largest paragraph, you could implement your `geometryChanged()` slot to do something like `if (_doSomethingPending == false) {_doSomethingPending = true; QTimer::singleShot(100, this, SLOT(DoSomethingOnce());}` ... and have another slot `DoSomethingOnce() {if (_doSomethingPending) {_doSomethingPending = false; DoSomething();}` ... that way multiple `geometryChanged()` signals that get triggered over a short period will still result in `DoSomething()` only being called a single time.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I've thought about the same approach, and that would indeed work, but I'd really like to avoid cruft like that!

Comment: I don’t see anything better than what you have described but I feel like it should be mentioned that QDesktopWidget was deprecated even in Qt5. Sure it sucks, but this is what happens if you rely on deprecated functionality. Using a mix of screenAdded and a timer seems like a pretty easy solution.

Comment: @DeanJohnson It's not bad, but it introduces race conditions which I'm not happy about. I don't have guarantees of how much time will elapse between each instance of `QScreen` firing its `geometryChanged` signal, and there'll be a brief period where my app's internal representation of the system's screen configuration is inaccurate. But in practice it shouldn't be an issue. And I was relying on a deprecated function because there was no alternative. Qt should have added a new method to replace `QDesktopWidget::resized`. Deprecrating functionality with no replacement is loss of functionality!

Comment: It does look there was some logic around the deprecation according to https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-62094. They don't call out the `resized` signal specifically so I don't know if there was anything specific considered to be wrong with that signal. There is some talk in some other related discussions about the whole concept of QDesktopWidget being broken because you can't nicely represent multi-screen geometry as one thing. Loss functionality, sure, but maybe it was for the best in the end? I don't know.

Comment: I'm sure there were valid reasons to remove `QDesktopWidget`, and `QScreen` almost replaces all of its functionality, with the exception of the `resized` signal. I'm thinking of making a feature request that they add a signal to `QGuiApplication` that fires when the overall system screen configuration changes, to go along with the other `QScreen` related signals there.

Comment: As I already told you elsewhere even QDesktopWidget fired the signal for each modified screen separately so no change from the old behavior, see https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/kernel/qdesktopwidget.cpp?h=5.15.2#n187

Comment: I stand corrected!

Comment: @chehrlic If you'd like to submit your code snippet from the Qt forums thread as an answer here, I'll mark it as correct